# Autowiring a collection via the constructor with Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have what seems to be a simple problem, as stated in the title. Here is the kind of class I have :

```
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    public Foo(@Qualifier("bar") Set<String> bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Which I try to run with the following spring context :

```
<context:annotation-config />
<util:set id="bar">
    <value>tata</value>
    <value>titi</value>
    <value>toto</value>
</util:set>
<bean id="foo" class="Foo" />
```

This fails to run with :

> No matching bean of type
>   [java.lang.String] found for
>   dependency [collection of
>   java.lang.String]: expected at least 1
>   bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=bar)}

Note that if I add other parameters to my constructor, it works fine. If I use setter injection, it works fine. I'm sure I miss something obvious ... do you know what ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Autowiring collections is not possible using the `@Autowired` annotation. An autowired collection means "to provide all beans of a particular type". Using the JSR-250 `@Resource` annotation, you can declare that you want a resource injected by its name, not its type. Or you inject the dependency explicitly.

> [...] beans which are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected via `@Autowired` since type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use `@Resource` for such beans, referring to the specific collection/map bean by unique name.

See [the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

As others stated it is impossible to use @Autowired for Strings and collections of String. You can use @Value with spring EL here assuming you have spring in version 3:

```
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    public Foo(@Value("#{bar}") Set<String> bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this is because Spring interprets the autowiring of a collection as "give me all beans of type `String`", rather than "give me the bean which is a collection of `String`". The error message supports that idea.

I don't think you can use autowiring for this. Short of manually wiring it up in the XML, the best I can suggest is:

```
public class Foo {  
   private @Resource Set<String> bar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and was inspired by [@rembisz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3367156/4851565). That answer didn't work on my version of Spring (4.1.3). When I checked the [SpEL documentation on bean references](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references), I found a different SpEL syntax to express bean references in autowired values that worked for me - `@beanname`. As such, the following code worked for me:

```
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    public Foo(@Value("#{@bar}") Set<String> bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```