# Spring autowiring a BlockingQueue

Tags: spring

I'm trying to autowire a parameterized blocking queue:

```
@Bean(name = "saveProductQueue")
public BlockingQueue<ProductDto> saveProductQueue() {
    return new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
}

@Autowired
private BlockingQueue<ProductDto> outputQueue;
```

However spring is complaining:

```
No qualifying bean of type [ProductDto] found for dependency
[collection of ProductDto]: expected at least 1
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I'm using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: It seem's Spring's autowiring cannot properly handle generic types (I thought this was fixed in 4.x) because @ Autowired and @ Autowired @ Qualifier("saveProductQueue") do not work, however @ Resource(name="saveProductQueue") does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BlockingQueue` is a collection and must be injected with @Resource

```
 @Resource
 private BlockingQueue<ProductDTO> saveProductQueue;
```

@Autowired works with the subtype:

```
@Autowired
private LinkedBlockingQueue<ProductDTO> saveProductQueue;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364283/autowiring-a-collection-via-the-constructor-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your 'outer' (a class where `saveProductQueue()` is defined) class with `@Configuration`

Comment: Sorry I should have made this clear, it is annotated with @Configuration and it's working for the other beans defined in it